# How to get as a stream any class loaded from a jar not in the classpath?

Tags: java, reflection, jar, classloader, urlclassloader

I have a web-app which I want to work roughly as follows:

Someone uploads a jar (say `myjar.jar`) along with the name of class to analyze (say `test.Test`). The exact purpose of analysis is irrelevant so assume that the web-app does some static analysis on it.

I am able to upload the jar and load the class in Java using the hacks described [here](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/javadoc/3.5/org/jgap/util/MultiClassLoader.html) and [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077572/learn-java/java-tip-70--create-objects-from-jar-files-.html#sthash.pgWuhVn3.dpuf) (MultiClassLoader).

If I know the methods inside the class, I can invoke them using reflection. Following assumes a method with signature `foo(String)`

```
Class c = jarLoader.loadClass("test.Test", true);
Object instance = c.newInstance();
Method foo = instance.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("foo", new Class[]{String.class}); 
   // foo takes one para String             
foo.setAccessible(true);
foo.invoke(instance, (Object) "hello");
```

Now, suppose, I need to find out what methods are there inside `test.Test`. To do this, I use the [ASM framework](http://asm.ow2.org/), **which needs the class as a stream**. This is where I am running into a problem. I am unable to do `getResourceAsStream` or its equivalents. This is what I tried:

```
Type t = org.objectweb.asm.Type.getType(c); // uses asm library
String url = t.getInternalName() + ".class";
c.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(url); // gives null
```

Same problem if I use:

```
c.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(c.getSimpleName() + ".class");
```

etc.

What is the right way to get resource as stream, where the resource is a class file loaded from a jar NOT in the class path. Note that the entire thing is done via a web-app.

EDIT: Getting methods is just an example. What I really want is to get the class as a stream. I need to use ASM because it gives me other information (such as parameter names), which I cannot get via `getDeclaredMethods` or `getMethods`.

Answer (score 1):

Re: *"Now I need to find out what methods are there inside test.Test"*

You get the class via `Class c = jarLoader.loadClass("test.Test", true);`. `Class` also has [`getDeclaredMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29) and [`getMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29).

---

EDIT: @Jus12, from your second link [Java Tip 70: Create objects from jar files!](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077572/learn-java/java-tip-70--create-objects-from-jar-files-.html#sthash.pgWuhVn3.dpuf):

`protected byte[] loadClassBytes (String className)`

ASM has a [`ClassReader(byte[] b)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html#ClassReader%28byte[]%29) constructor.

Comment: Please see my edit. I want more than get methods. I need the class as a stream, because that's what the asm analyzer needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html), which takes a `List` of `URL`s in its constructor. You can then load the class by invoking the [`loadClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String)) method on the `URLClassLoader` instance to get the `Class<?>` object for the class that you are after. Once you have that, you can then use reflection to create instances, and/or get general information about the class.

I have not tried, but the `URLClassLoader` does also have a [`getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) method.